# Change dates around using Excel formula

Tags: excel, formula

I have a column with dates that are currently showing as mm/dd/yyyy and I am trying to convert to dd/mm/yyyy.
For some reason using the format option this is not working. I've then tried the following formula but this is not working correctly either.

```
=TEXT(MID(A2,3,2)&"/"&LEFT(A2,2)&"/"&RIGHT(A2,4),"mm/dd/yyyy")
```

Can anyone suggest a solution to what should be a simple fix.

[image: Example-Screenshot]

Comment: Try using the `Text To Columns` on the range `A:A` in the first step click `Delimiter` --> `Next` --> Second Step --> Click Nothing --> `Next` --> Third Step --> Click on Dates --> change to `MDY` --> Finish --> if cells or range are not formatted to your desired date formatting it will return as numbers and you can change accordingly. You dont need a formula. If there is something else which is obstructing to convert then you may look into formulas. Bt `TTC` should work

Comment: I tried this option as well but did not work, in the screenshot you will see 03/01/2023, this should actually be 01/03/2023 which I think is confusing excel

Comment: Since you do not have time remove the time addition part on the dup formula.  So: `=--TEXTJOIN("/",,FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(TEXT(A1,"d/m/yy")&" ",FIND(" ",TEXT(A1,"d/m/yy")&" ")-1),"/","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b["&{2,1,3}&"]"))`